# Loading data from a server using jquery $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What im about to do is to send data to the server through a form and to a php-script. Then I want to get it back and place it in the right spot using Jquery. I don't know why, but this solution doesnt seem to work as im just getting the "No text in the textbox!". Does someone have any tips?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#send").click(function(event) {           
                $.post("target.php", {
                    melding: $("#input").val().
                }, function(data){
                    $("#meldinger").after("<div>" + data + "</div>");
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = date();
    </script>
    <title>Meldingssystem</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Meldingsutveksling</h1>
    <form action="target.php" method="post">
    <textarea id="input" name="input" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea>
    <br/><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <h2>Meldinger</h2>
    <div id="meldinger">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['input'])) {
     $melding = $_POST['input'];
    echo $melding;
}
else {
    echo "No text in the textbox!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if (!empty($_POST['input'])) {
     $melding = $_POST['input'];
    echo $melding;
}
else {
    echo "No text in the textbox!";
}
```

Should be

```
if (!empty($_POST['melding'])) {
     $melding = $_POST['melding'];
    echo $melding;
}
else {
    echo "No text in the textbox!";
}
```

because there is no input POST parameter sent

Answer (score 0):

first, please read https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

your php script expects data in the `input` field. but your jquery POST doesn't put anything in an `input` field.

instead try something like:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        input: $("#input").val()
    },
    datatype: "text",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        $("#meldinger").after("<div>" + data + "</div>");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert("zog zog");
    }   
};
```

Notice that `input` is present in the `data` parameter.